# OpenCV (C++) to process image data coming from JavaScript / Web Assembly

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, webassembly, emscripten

I have successfully ported a C++ script to wasm but now I am having trouble sending data to it from my web app.

Long story short, in the C++ "version" of the app I am using OpenCV to open two images, that get passed in via the cli - something along the lines of:

```
#include <opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int calc(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat img1_temp, img2_temp;
    img1_temp = imread(argv[1],-1);
    img2_temp = imread(argv[2],-1);
    // further processing ...
}
```

this works from the CLI like: `./app one.jpg two.jpg`.

When porting the app to wasm, I can no longer use the CLI to send the image and of course I cannot send the file(s) so I ended up having the following code (this is now client side JavaScript):

```
// url is a remote image
const urlToUint8Array = async url => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  const arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  return arr;
};

const waModule = await WAModule();
document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  waModule.FS.writeFile('in1.ext', one, { encoding: 'binary' });
  waModule.FS.writeFile('in2.ext', two, { encoding: 'binary' });
  waModule._calc('in1.ext', 'in2.ext')); // this does not work
});
```

The question is, how can I send the image from JS to wasm. I have also tried to modify the C++ file to use `imdecode` instead of `imread` (and recompile the wasm) but I'm not sure if that's the right path.

To summarise, I am looking for a way to send image data for further analysis from my client side JavaScript over to WASM to be process by OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have mainly used enscripten and by no means I am an expert in this. I give my 2 cents in case that it might help you:

1. Wasm has his own memory. It is a sandbox to which you `transfer` the data. This means that if you created some memory on JS side there will going to be a copy of this data when transferred to C++ side.
2. From security purposes, this memory is not shared. The one way to allocate memory and use it for both WASM and JS is to allocate the memory on WASM side and use it in JS. (`Module.HEAP8` etc.).

Now coming back to your question with having this in mind:

You can in fact give WASM the security permissions to read from a certain folder or to give some permissions to the file system. (https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html#file-system-runtime-environment) and here you have an example based on enscripten library https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/tests/fs/test_nodefs_rw.c.

You can allocate the memory of the buffer on WASM side, use the Uint8Buffer to read the data, which is shared by the two and you do your computation.